# Access rule on odoo12ce does not work even when it was correctly added

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am actually working on an module and on the res.partner model I've added a new boolean column "associated" and I want to create a group where the users in it can just see the contacts with True

```
  associated = fields.Boolean(default = False, string="associated?")
```

then I created a new group

```
  <record id="group_coop_tecnical" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Tecnical</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_coop"/>
  </record>
```

and the access rule

```
  <record model="ir.rule" id="associated_group">
    <field name="name">Associated for the department</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"></field>
    <field name="domain_force">[('associated', '=', True)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[ (4, ref('group_coop_tecnical'))]"/>
  </record>
```

The problem is that when I log in with a user of the group "group_coop_tecnical" the filter doesn't work and all the records are shown. In addition, when I look for the rule in the technical tab, it is already there and the users belong to the group. Can someone helpme please, maybe am I forgetting something??

Comment: Is the user you're logging in with in other groups with res.partner access rules? Because non global rules (without groups) are OR-ed.

Comment: when I set the rule as global works fine for the non admin user, but the rule applies also for the admin. If I set the group for the rule, it doesn't work anymore.